# Switching data from array to vector

Tags: c++, function, vector

I'm trying to convert my array to a vector, yet I'm having trouble printing it.
It says in int main() in my for loop that v is undefined. When I define
vector v; inside int main() the program compiles and runs and yet prints nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

vector<int> a2v(int x[], int n)
{
    vector<int> v(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(x[i]);
    } 
    return(v);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a2v(int x[], int n);

    int array[] = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18};

    a2v(array, 8);

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] <<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Does it even compile to you?

Comment: "It says in int main() in my for loop that v is undefined" – yeah it is, why should it magically exist unless you declared it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of fundamental knowledge about the language. Stack Overflow is not a language tutorial site.

Comment: You are not storing the results of a2v function anywhere. Declaring `v` in the `a2v` makes it visible only in `a2v` function.

Comment: This question does satisfy: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself" - so voting to keep it open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your program corrected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> a2v(int x[], int n)
{
     vector<int> v(0);
     v.reserve(n); //optional
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
          v.push_back(x[i]);
     }
     return(v);
}

int main()
{
     int array[] = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18};

     auto v = a2v(array, 8);

     for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
     {
          cout << v[i] <<" ";
     }
     cout << endl;

     return(0);
}
```

There were 2 errors:

1. In the function `a2v`, you instantiated a vector of 0 with length n, and then you pushed back other elements;
2. You were not defining `v` inside the main, as the return value of `a2v`

Comment: @Quentin I guess you're right! I'll edit the answer ;)

Comment: I was confused there for a moment, haha !

Comment: It seems that I've been confused much longer :-/ Thanks for your correction!

Answer (score 1):

The vector you want to read is the return of the `a2v` function.

But there is a lot more simpler than that to go from C-array to vector array , I put here the example in found the vector reference web page :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

```
int myints[] = {16,2,77,29};
std::vector<int> fifth (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );
```

Comment: Why not `std::begin(myints)`/`std::end(myints)` instead of `sizeof` juggling ?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a variable, such as your vector v, you always do it in a certain scope. The body of a function such as a2v, or main, is an example of a possible scope. So if you only do it in the function a2v, that's the only scope where it will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

> It says in int main() in my for loop that v is undefined.

Well it will be because there is no `v` in `main()`

```
a2v(array, 8);
```

The above function call returns a vector so you need to collect the returned vector like

```
vector<int> v=a2v(array,8)
```

Also,

```
vector<int> v(n);//creates a vector of size n
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    v.push_back(x[i]);//adds n more elements to the vector
}
```

The returned vector has `2n` elements and not `n`

Finally you could directly create a vector from an array as

```
vector<int> v(arr,arr+n);//where n is the number of elements in arr
```